# Check two tables and find values not in both using SQL

Tags: sql, database, join

I have two tables which I am returning a reference code from. I need to compare both these lists to find references that exists only in tableA or tableB, NOT in both.

As an example, if table A and table B had the following data

```
TABLE A References
01
02
04

TABLE B References
01
22
```

I would expect to return a table with the following

```
TABLE C References
02
04
22
```

The SQL for this has me stumped. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this,

```
  SELECT COL1 FROM
    (
      SELECT Col1 FROM TABLE_A
      UNION ALL
      SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE_B
    ) X
     GROUP BY COL1
     HAVING COUNT(*) =1
```

This query will also eliminate if any value comes twice in the same table.

Comment: Worth adding the caveat that this will also eliminate values which exist multiple times in the *same* table (whether such a situation applies for the OP is as yet unknown - probably not in this case, but still worth adding as a warning)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ; I have added a warning in my answer.

Comment: In this case there will never be a value multiple times in the same table so this worked great!

Answer (score 3):

```
select
    COALESCE(a.Value,b.Value)
FROM
    a
        full outer join
    b
        on
           a.Value = b.Value
WHERE
    a.Value is null or
    b.Value is null
```

Should do the trick. The `FULL OUTER JOIN` attempts to match up all rows from the two tables. The `WHERE` clause then removes those rows where a match was found, leaving (as a result) only those rows where a row only existed in `a` or `b`.

The `COALESCE()` is then used to give the result as a single column, as per your expected output. If you preferred, you could remove the `COALESCE` and have `SELECT a.Value,b.Value` which will have `NULL`s but will make it immediately obvious *which* table contains the value.

Comment: This is IMHO the *canonical* answer. The `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` kludge is probably preferred by people who are exposed to mysql (which does not have FULL JOIN, as I was told yesterday)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server:

```
(  select 'A' as source, reference
   from tableA
   EXCEPT
   select 'A' as source, reference
   from tableB)
UNION ALL
(  select 'B' as source, reference
   from tableB
   EXCEPT
   select 'B' as source, reference
   from tableA)


==================
source | reference
==================
 A       02
 A       04 
 B       22
```

Find everything in A **except** those that are in B, and add also (**UNION ALL**) what is in B but not (**except**) in A.  This identifies where each reference is from, but you can of course drop the "Source" column from each of the 4 component queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Distinct ( isnull(A.References,B.Referecces))   
from A full join B on A.References<>B.References  
where ( not exists ( Select * from B as B1 where B1.References=A.References )  and A.References is not null )  or  
( not exists ( Select * from A as a1  where a1.References=B.References )  and B.References is not null )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

```
select a.*
FROM
    tblA a LEFT JOIN tblB b on a.ColRef=b.ColRef
where b.ColRef IS NULL
UNION ALL
select b.*
FROM
    tblB b LEFT JOIN tblA a on b.ColRef=a.ColRef
where a.ColRef IS NULL
```

OR

```
select * from(
    select * from tblA
    union
    select * from tblB
)x where x.ColRef NOT IN (select a.ColRef From tblA a JOIN tblB b on a.ColRef=b.ColRef)
```

Answer (score 0):

Self anti-join on a CTE:

```
WITH two AS (
        SELECT val AS val, 'A' AS flag FROM lutser_a
        UNION ALL
        SELECT val AS val, 'B' AS flag FROM lutser_b
        )
SELECT *
FROM two t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM two nx
        WHERE nx.val = t.val
        AND nx.flag <> t.flag
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

Explanation:

```
SELECT ISNULL(TABLE_A.Col1,TABLE_B.Col1) 
FROM TABLE_A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.Col1 = TABLE_B.Col1 
WHERE TABLE_A.Col1<> TABLE_B.Col1
```

The Join Part Of The Query Will Give Us The Table like this

01 Null
02   02
null 03

The Where part will remove Duplicated values

01 Null
null 03

The IsNull part will select the value that is not null from the table

01
03

Comment: You need a FULL JOIN (like @Damien_The_Believer above)

Comment: It's also strongly suggested to add some description to your answers as the code isn't self-descriptive for everyone.